# How can i detect which node tapped in ArCore Flutter

Tags: flutter, augmented-reality, arcore, android-augmented-reality

I need to detect which node tapped in ArCore in flutter

```
arCoreController!.onNodeTap = (name) => onTapHandler(name);
```

didn't get the expected name.

Answer (score 0):

The below logic works perfectly fine. Please refer to [this](https://github.com/giandifra/arcore_flutter_plugin/blob/master/example/lib/screens/custom_object.dart) sample. If you're facing error when running this project, refer to [this](https://github.com/giandifra/arcore_flutter_plugin/issues/179#issuecomment-1163516074) fix. Hope this helps !

```
void _onArCoreViewCreated(ArCoreController controller) {
    arCoreController = controller;
    arCoreController?.**onNodeTap** = (name) => onTapHandler(name);
    arCoreController?.onPlaneTap = _handleOnPlaneTap;
  }

...

  void onTapHandler(String name) {
    print("Flutter: onNodeTap");
    showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) =>
          AlertDialog(content: Text('onNodeTap on $name')),
    );
  }
```